# error: name lookup of 'i' changed for ISO 'for' scoping

Tags: c++, arrays, function, average, mean

I have looked at other topics similar to this and still cannot find out what is wrong with my code. The following is a function in my program to find the Mean (Average) of Arrays. I get the error in the title: error: name lookup of 'i" changed for ISO 'for' scoping. following with note: if you use '-fpermissize' g++ will accept your code.

```
double GetMean ( double Array[], int ArrayLength )
{
    int Sum, Mean;
    for ( int i = 0; i < ArrayLength; i++ )
    {
         Sum = Sum + Array[i];
    }

    Mean = Sum / Array[i];

    return Mean;
}
```

Ideas and explanation would be lovely so I can understand what the hell I'm doing wrong :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < ArrayLength; i++)
```

When you define `i` in the `for` header like this, its scope is inside the `for` loop. You can't use  it outside the `for` loop like `Mean = Sum / Array[i];` in your code.

Change it to:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < ArrayLength; i++)
```

Also note you never initialize `Sum`.

Comment: Thank you so much. Frustrates me that it was just that little line that caused that big an issue.

Answer (score 0):

This statement

Mean = Sum / Array[i];

makes no sense.

As for the error then you are trying to use varaible i in expression Array[i] in the statement above outside its scope. It is defined only within the loop.

Also you forgot to initialize variable Sum and I think it should have type double.

The function could look like

```
double GetMean( const double Array[], int ArrayLength )
{
    double  Sum = 0.0;

    for ( int i = 0; i < ArrayLength; i++ )
    {
         Sum = Sum + Array[i];
    }

    return ArrayLength == 0 ? 0.0 : Sum / ArrayLength;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All the comments mentioned are referring to your code.
I have corrected it. Have a look.

```
double GetMean ( double Array[], int ArrayLength )
{
    int i;
    double Mean,Sum=0;                                //You must initialise Sum=0 and you should declare Mean and Sum as double otherwise your calculated mean would always come out to be an integer 
    for (i = 0; i < ArrayLength; i++ )         //The variable i has scope within the loop only in your case. To use it outside the loop you should declare it outside and before the loop
    {
         Sum = Sum + Array[i];
    }

    Mean = Sum /i;                        //Logical error Mean=(sum of terms)/(Number of terms). You will get unexpected output from your logic.  

    return Mean;
}
```