# aphabetical order nested data structure c++

Tags: c++

i'm trying to get my code aphabetically sort elements of a nested data structure in more effcient way. Here is a piece of my code:

```
 struct famous {
     string name;
     string emp;
     int proes;
     int mins;
     string mit;
 };

 struct personal {
     famous per[500];
     int np;
 };

 void delete(personal & p, int ndx){
     int mid = p.np;
     for (int i=ndx; i<mid-1; i++){
         p.per[i].name = p.per[i+1].nom;
         p.per[i].emp = p.per[i+1].emp;
         p.per[i].mins = p.per[i+1].mins;
         p.per[i].mit = p.per[i+1].mit;
     }
     p.np = mid-1;
  }

  void sort(personal & p){
      string tmp;
      int pers;
      personal vtmp;
      pers = p.np;
      tmp = p.per[0].name;
      for (int pos=0; pos<pers; pos++){
          for (int ndx=1; ndx<p.np; ndx++){
              if (tmp>p.per[ndx].name){tmp=p.per[ndx].name;}
          }
          vtmp.per[pos] = p.per[ndx]; //line 107
          deletePers(p,ndx);
          tmp = p.per[0].name;
      }
  }
```

The problem comes when I try to compile the code, I get this:

> D:\main.cpp|107|error: name lookup of 'ndx' changed for ISO 'for' scoping [-fpermissive]|

How could I fix this?

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: possible duplicate of [error: name lookup of 'i' changed for ISO 'for' scoping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26552165/error-name-lookup-of-i-changed-for-iso-for-scoping)

Comment: in `sort` function scope of `ndx` is in side `for` loop only and you are using it outside `for` loop also. declare `ndx` at the starting of your sort function.

Comment: you should also consider changing the name of delete function as it is a c++ keyword

Comment: You should definitely use a `std::vector<famous>` instead of your homecooked `personal` struct. Then you can also use `std::sort()` on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 for (int pos=0; pos<pers; pos++){
      for (int ndx=1; ndx<p.np; ndx++){
          if (tmp>p.per[ndx].name){tmp=p.per[ndx].name;}
      }
 vtmp.per[pos] = p.per[ndx];//line 107
```

scope of  `ndx` is not outside the for loop.
declare it outside of for.

Also rename your `delete()` function as `delete` is reserved,and

```
   p.per[i].name = p.per[i+1].nom; //should be per[i+1].name
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this function

```
void sort(personal & p){
      int ndx =1;  // declare ndx at the starting of sor function
      string tmp;
      int pers;
      personal vtmp;
      pers = p.np;
      tmp = p.per[0].name;
      for (int pos=0; pos<pers; pos++){
          for (ndx=1; ndx<p.np; ndx++){  // remove int here
              if (tmp>p.per[ndx].name){tmp=p.per[ndx].name;}
          }
          vtmp.per[pos] = p.per[ndx]; //line 107
          deletePers(p,ndx);
          tmp = p.per[0].name;
      }
  }
```

As you are using `for (int ndx=1; ndx<p.np; ndx++){`

scope of `ndx` will remain inside for loop only, so will not able to use it outside for loop.
So it will be good to declare `ndx` outside the loop.